# Redefining Lexical Tokens With Javacc

Tags: token, javacc

I'm quite new to creating language syntax with Javacc and i need to find a way to allow the user to redefine the definition of a token in code.

For example, the line

```
REDEFINE IF FOO
```

Should change the Definition of "IF" from

```
  < IF: "IF" >
```

To

```
  < IF: "FOO" >
```

If this is not possible, what would be the best way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with a token action that changes the kind field of the token.

Something like the following.  [Untested code follows.  If you use it, please correct any errors in this answer.]

Make a token manager declaration of a hash map:

```
TOKEN_MGR_DECLS: {
    public java.util.HashMap<String,Integer> keywordMap = new java.util.HashMap<String,Integer>()  ;
    {   keywordMap.put( "IF", ...Constants.IF); }
}
```

Make a definition for identifiers.

```
TOKEN : { <ID : (["a"-"z","A"-"Z"])(["a"-"z","A"-"Z","0"-"9"])* >
               { if( keywordMap.containsKey( matchedToken.image ) ) {
                     matchedToken.kind = keywordMap.get( matchedToken.image ) ; }
               }
         }
```

Make definitions for the key words.  These need to come after then definition of ID.  Really these are just here so that the kinds are created.  They will be unreachable and may cause warnings.

```
TOKEN : { <IF : "A"> | ... }
```

In the parser you need to define redefine

```
void redefine() :
{
    Token oldToken;
    Token newToken;
}
{
    <REDEFINE> oldToken=redefinableToken() newToken=redefinableToken() 
    {
        if( ...TokenManager.keywordMap.containsKey( oldToken.image ) ) {
            ...TokenManager.keywordMap.remove( oldToken.image ) ;
            ...TokenManager.keywordMap.add( newToken.image, oldToken.kind ) ; }
        else {
             report an error }
    }
}

Token redefinableToken() : 
{ Token t ; }
{
    t=<ID>  {return t ;}
|   t=<IF>  {return t ;}
| ...
}
```

See the FAQ (4.14) for warnings about trying to alter the behaviour of the lexer from the parser.  Long story short: avoid lookahead.

---

Another approach is to simply have one token kind, say `ID`, and handle everything in the parser.  See FAQ 4.19 on "Replacing keywords with semantic lookahead".  Here lookahead will be less of a problem because semantic actions in the parser aren't executed during syntactic lookahead (FAQ 4.10).

Comment: Thanks for the reply theodore. I'm getting a problem when referring to the keywordMap throughout the parser (and for the <ID> token definition) - Unresolved compilation problems: keywordMap cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Comment: UPDATE: I fixed this problem I just commented, still got another problem but try and fix it. ill repsond shortly

Comment: Thank you very much this solution worked very well with some minor tweaks :)

Comment: If there are any errors in the answer, feel free to improve it.